# How to authenticate the express API to allow only logged In user

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

say for example in express.js if I'm having the api like [this](https://reqres.in/api/unknown/2). I need to allow access to api only for logged in users.

Let me know how to authenticate it by JWT.

Refer my code which was hosted in [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/json-web-token?path=server.js:18:3).

Comment: Can you add what you have tried or researched? And why/how that did not work?

Comment: @JochenLutz I did a research on securing API by JWT and I end up here [https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken] But i'm not sure how to integrate it. It would be great if you give some example. Refer my code here 
 https://glitch.com/edit/#!/json-web-token?path=server.js:18:3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the token based authentication by [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) npm package. Refer my code at [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/json-web-token?path=server.js:20:0)

Demo Link: https://json-web-token.glitch.me/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/).

It works well with express and has configurations for multiple types of authentication mechanisms such as Google, Facebook and Twitter. You can also configure it to work with a simple username password authentication method

Here is a good tutorial by [JonathanMH](https://jonathanmh.com/express-passport-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-beginners/) on exactly what you are asking for

Comment: is it possible to integrate with jsonwebtoken [https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken] package?

Comment: I've updated my answer, that should give you a better clarity

Comment: I'm trying to implement without passport.js. Refer the sample here http://www.bentedder.com/part-2-node-js-implementation-of-jwt-json-web-tokens/ - Here is my code at glitch https://glitch.com/edit/#!/json-web-token?path=server.js:18:3